# Why is Identity not returned when parameter is passed?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-insert

I have a function that executes an Insert command and returns the identity column (if any). Parameters can be passed optionally.

When I don't pass any parameters, the function is able to return the Identity of the row inserted. However, when any parameter is passed in the insert statement, the identity column is not returned - even though we are clearing all parameters before calling Scope_Identity().

Here is the function:

```
Public Shared Function InsertSQL(aCommand As String, aParamList As String, ParamArray aParam() As Object) As Integer
    Dim lConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection

    ' Create new connection
    lConn = DAL.CreateConnection()

    ' Create command object
    Dim lCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(aCommand, lConn)
    lCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    ' If parameters are supplied, add to command
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aParamList) Then
        Dim lParams() As String
        lParams = aParamList.Replace(" ", String.Empty).Split(CChar(","))
        ' Check parameters supplied match
        If lParams.Length <> aParam.Length Then Return 0

        For lX As Integer = 0 To lParams.Length - 1
            If aParam(lX) Is Nothing Then aParam(lX) = DBNull.Value
            If TypeOf (aParam(lX)) Is SqlClient.SqlParameter Then lCommand.Parameters.Add(CType(aParam(lX), SqlClient.SqlParameter)) Else lCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(lParams(lX), aParam(lX))
        Next
    End If

    Try
        lConn.Open()
        lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        lCommand.Parameters.Clear()
        lCommand.CommandText = "Select IsNull(Scope_Identity(),0)"
        Return CInt(lCommand.ExecuteScalar)

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Catch error
        Return -1
    Finally
        lConn.Close()
        lCommand.Dispose()
    End Try

    Return 0
End Function
```

If I call without parameters, the identity is returned successfully:

```
Dim Identity As Integer = InsertSQL("Insert AA(Value) Values('Test')", "")
```

If I call with parameters, the identity is returned as 0.

```
Dim Identity As Integer = InsertSQL("Insert AA(Value) Values(@T)", "@T", "Test")
```

Any idea why?

Comment: When you call it with parameters, does it actually insert the row?

Comment: Hypothesis (not actually verified with Profiler): when you use parameters, `sp_executesql` is used to execute the statement, which defeats `SCOPE_IDENTITY` since it introduces a new scope. When you don't use parameters, it executes the statement directly. If my hypothesis is correct, the workaround would be to include the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` into the batch itself (using the `;` separator) and using only `.ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @BrianStork: Yes, row is inserted both cases.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: You are right! I remove ExecuteNonQuery() and appended the Select Scope_Identity() to the original command. It returns the identity. I consider this behavior really strange - I would have assumed these commands are running the same scope! Apparently that's not the case :(

Comment: Also consider the ultimate workaround to custom low-level code like this, which is to use Dapper. :P Custom code like this is often less than optimal, for example, [`.AddWithValue` is problematic](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and you should be using `Using` to dispose of things rather than `Finally` (an exception might occur before you ever get to the `Try`).

Comment: I fully agree. This is a legacy application and we're slowly porting code to use Dapper.

Comment: Put `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in the same batch